# How do I map an object representing a collection with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I've got an existing database containing a number of lists, e.g:

- List of events:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| date                | name                    | description | notification_needed |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2024-08-25 00:00:00 | It`s 25-th of August!   | NULL        |                   1 |
| 2024-08-27 00:00:00 | It`s 27-th of August!   | NULL        |                   1 |
| 2024-09-03 00:00:00 | It`s 3-rd of September! | NULL        |                   1 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

- A queue of users (joined with table Users for the sake of readability):

```
+----------+-----------------------+---------+------------+
| position | username              | status  | first_name |
+----------+-----------------------+---------+------------+
|        2 | tg_touch_purple       | ADMIN   | Eugene     |
|        3 | tg_hands_off_the_corn | REGULAR | Carl       |
|        1 | tg_glassk             | REGULAR | Joe        |
+----------+-----------------------+---------+------------+
```

I'd like to see their contents in a `HashMap<LocalDate, Event>` and `LinkedList< User>` respectively. However these two collections are not a part of some class and clearly represent self-sufficient entities, thus I can't map them with conventional collection-related annotations like `@OneToMany`.

I've tried creating a "position" field inside the `User` class (someting like converting one-to-many relations to many-to-one). This move noticably simplifies everything, but seems rather illogical. A 'date' field in `Event` class looks much better, but still.

Creating `Queue` and `EventDate` (?) classes to represent these tables is also an acceptable solution, but it leaves me with a basic list of Queue/EventDate, which I'll then have to manually convert to desired collections.

I can always stick with using a native query, but for some reason unparametrized createNativeQuery method is now deprecated, which renders it virtually useless for this purpose. Moreover, it doesn't look as a Hibernate-like solution at all.

What I'm really looking for is a universal and automated way to load any of these collections from the database.